# Pycharm unable to find dotenv even though I installed it

Tags: python, import, module, pycharm, python-3.10

I downloaded `python-dotenv` successfully using pip but for some reason pycharm doesnt detect it when I do `import dotenv` even though I added the package manually to pycharm by doing `File > Settings > Project > Python Interpreter > + > python-dotenv > Install Package` in which pycharm says it has successfully downloaded `python-dotenv`. I tried doing `import python-dotenv` but python mistakes python and dotenv as separate packages so it doesn't work. Am I just getting the package name wrong? I tried using the inbuilt package installer for pycharm but it gives me an error saying it can't find `dotenv` which is probably is because it says it executed the command `pip install dotenv` to install the package. Also I tried closing pycharm and opening it again but that doesn't fix the problem too.

Comment: I tried it on my end and it worked fine for me. Do you have multiple versions of Python installed on your machine? If so, check to see if you are running the script with the same Python version as your default pip Python version.

Comment: @HaruFrost I only have python 3.10 installed on my pc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out the problem, I just uninstalled python-dotenv using pip and reinstalled it. Actually saw this solution on the internet but it said to also uninstall dotenv which I did first, and pip said it couldn't find it so I thought the solution wouldn't work and gave up lol.